# php curl search API OAuth

Tags: php, api, twitter

My homework is that using OAuth, php, curl to get the location information where the twitter twittes keyword "SteveJob".

I use API of twitter and the URL like this `"https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?query=SteveJob"`. I downloaded some code from the Internet and modify as below:

```
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
    {
        $r = array(); 
        ksort($params);
        foreach($params as $key=>$value){
            $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value); 
        }

        return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); 
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth '; 
    $values = array(); 
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; 
    $r .= implode(', ', $values); 
    return $r; 
}

//$url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/totals.json";
$url= "https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?query=EN0745?&callback=?";

$oauth_access_token = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$oauth_access_token_secret = $_SESSION['oauth_secret'];
$consumer_key = **My consumer key**;
$consumer_secret = **My consumer secret**;

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                'oauth_version' => '1.0');
$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
//echo $oauth_signature;
echo $json;
curl_close($feed);
```

The result I get only simple:

```
{
    "result": {
        "places": []
    },
    "query": {
        "type": "search",
        "params": {
            "granularity": "neighborhood",
            "query": "SteveJob?",
            "trim_place": false,
            "accuracy": 0,
            "autocomplete": false
        },
        "url": "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?granularity=neighborhood&query=SteveJob%3F&accuracy=0&trim_place=false&autocomplete=false"
    }
}
```

How can I do my homework? Thanks for the help.

---

I'm going to tell exactly my homework :
Add a twitter search1 capability to the website. The search should auto update every 20 seconds and carry out searches for the most recent mentions of the hash tag '#EN0700'. The tweets should be shown in a list with the date, and author's username on twitter, the tweet location data (where the  tweet is tweed). I try to use https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?query=Twitter%20HQ in dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/geo/search example, but it does not display the location result. Does my URL is correct. And the other thing is if I use api.twitter.com/1/users/search.json?q=Twitter%20API, I received that "{"error":"Could not authenticate you.","request":"/1/users/search.json?q=EN0745"}" although I have registered my application in the oAUTH. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You should decode `JSON` which is called `$json` first by using `json_encode()`.

Than `JSON` gonna be an `object`. Look at that example:

```php
$json = json_decode($json);

//access the result > places
$places = $json -> result -> places;

//iterate places
foreach($places as $place){
    //...
}
```

**Notice** that, there is no places in your json output. Check your api url.
You may use this [example search](https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/search.json?query=New%20York).